# Connection errors after project moved to a new server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, active-directory

I have been experiencing run-time errors in my application since the project files were moved to a new file server this past weekend as well the retirement of several old domain controllers. One is an `LdapException` (The connection cannot be established) when creating a new `PrincipalContext` as in the code below:

```
WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());

using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    UP = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, wp.Identity.Name);
}
```

I've tried a number of things including specifying various domain names and my network administrator has tried several things, but no luck.

I am also receiving an `EntityException` (The underlying provider failed on Open) when trying to get data from my MySQL database using EF as in the following code (crashes on the second line).

```
p = new pEntities();

Statuses = new ObservableCollection<status>(p.statuses);
```

I've taken several drastic steps that haven't solved my issues:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio
- Uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL
- Deleted my user profile (this fixed some errors I was getting in VS, but not he run-time errors in the application itself)

I've tested the code in a completely new project and get the same errors, so it doesn't seem related to the project itself. I've also read quite a few SO and other posts on the two errors, but haven't been able to figure anything out. Is there something else I should be doing?

**UPDATE**

So, I moved my project to a local drive (C:) rather than the network, and now both errors are resolved, but I have no idea *why* that would fix it. Are there any known issues with running projects from networks drives that could cause these types of errors?

Comment: Do you still need to run it from network drives?

Comment: No. I can make do building the project on my local drive, and the final version will be installed on users' local drives, so it doesn't need to work from a network drive. It's just strange because it was working fine on the network before the recent changes.

The only real frustration is I'll probably need to make a duplicate of the files on the network drive to ensure it gets backed up regularly.